# Binding initialization to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, syncfusion

I have an HTML page where I have some elements that I have initialized with the Syncfusion widget [ejMenu](https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejmenu) using the following code:

```
$("#contextMenu").ejMenu({
  menuType: ej.MenuType.ContextMenu,
  openOnClick: false,
  contextMenuTarget: '.blocks'
});
```

The above code initializes every element with the `.block` class to have a menu defined in the element with id `#contextMenu`.

The problem is that I'm dynamically creating other elements with class `.block` and I'd like that they have the same behaviour as the others, but the menu is not displayed.

Is there a way to have the ejMenu to work also on the newly created elements?

**UPDATE**

I've added the re-initialization of the ejMenu right after I add a new element but it doesn't work, still the same behaviour.

Here is the "fiddle" where you can see it in action:
https://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/qymetmtd
 (The blue blocks are the one where the context menu is enabled)

The new elements are added by cloning an existing element, and then appended to the container:

```
function addNewRow() {
    lineCount = lineCount + 1;    
    var $row = $('#template .activity-row').clone();
    $('.event', $row).attr('id', 'event' + lineCount);
    $('.event', $row).html('New Event');

    $('.lines', $row).attr('id', 'line' + lineCount);
    $('.blocks', $row).attr('id', 'block' + lineCount); 

    $('.content', $row).html('This is a new activity!');

    $('#contentContainer').append($row);

}
```

and on the click event on the button that add the new element I have:

```
$('#addNewEvent').on('click', function () {
    addNewRow();
    $("#contextMenu").ejMenu({
        menuType: ej.MenuType.ContextMenu,
        openOnClick: false,
        contextMenuTarget: '.blocks'
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, you will need to also instantiate `.ejMenu()` every time you add new `.blocks` elements to the DOM.

Comment: In some case it can be interesting to use the `MutationObserver` API, but if you controls the hook that add the `.block` elements, it's clearly simpler to call `.ejMenu()` as @RoryMcCrossan said.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've tried your suggestion but it still doesn't work, and the new elements do not show the menu on right click. Maybe is the way I add the them, using append()?

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better that you destroy the previously rendered context menu via its instance, before rendering it again for the dynamic element

```
$('#addNewEvent').on('click', function () {
  addNewRow();
  var obj = $("#contextMenu").data("ejMenu"); // Accessing control's instance
  obj.destroy(); // Use the destroy method from the instance
  $("#contextMenu").ejMenu({
    menuType: ej.MenuType.ContextMenu,
    openOnClick: false,
    contextMenuTarget: '.blocks'
  });
});
```

Modified Example: https://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/fw2sqwb0